# CakePHP - Entity Object Not Accessible

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to loop through all the properties of the `$entity` variable on the `beforeSave()` method.

`debug($entity)` returns:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Student) {

    'id' => (int) 5690,
    'institution_id' => (int) 35,
    'contact_id' => null,
    'id_number' => '0000000000',
    ....
```

However, when I try to look through the object, using

```
foreach ($entity as $key => $value) {
   debug($key);
   debug($value);
}
```

the foreach loop does not even run. I investigate by `debug(count($entity))`, and it returns 1.

How can I loop through the properties of my entity?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: An entity is an object with properties, not an array of values.

Comment: The loop will not run if all the properties are `private` or `protected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of *accessible* and *non-static* properties of an object, use function [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

I would also check if the `$entity` object is not actually an *array* containing a single entity object.